# retrieve url Get parameters from remote server using php

Tags: php, server, remote-access

i have a remote server with ip 125.x.x.x and i installed httpd(apache) and php7.3 on that server, what i've done is creating a file test.php in /var/www/html on that server which has the following code (just for testing) :

```
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">this is your informations</h5>
    <p class="card-text"><b>Email</b> : <?php echo $_GET['email']; ?></p>
    <p class="card-text"><b>Message</b> : <?php echo $_GET['message']; ?></p>
</div>
```

now from my local machine i'm trying 125.x.x.x/test.php?email=user@example.com&message=hello

the problem it's only displaying the html part and i cant see the url GET parameters!!

Update:
the problem was with the configuration of apache and php, to do so i advice you to follow this link : https://elearning.wsldp.com/pcmagazine/install-php-7-centos-7-linux-server/

Comment: Have you enabled PHP on your server?

Comment: Is the page getting treated as an PHP page? View source in your browser. Do you see the PHP code? If you do then the page is not being parsed for PHP tags. You need to make sure your webserver is configured with PHP.

Comment: <p class="card-text"><b>Email</b> : <!--?php echo "hello ".$_GET['email']; ?--></p> this is what i see when i inspect the page

Comment: i found the problem, i need to configure httpd.conf to load php modules.